# Python Typing: Type[UnionType]

Tags: casting, mypy, python-typing

I am having a function `safe_cast` which casts a value to a given type, but raises if the value fails to comply with the type at runtime:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def safe_cast(t: type[T], value: Any) -> T:
    if isinstance(value, t):
        return cast(T, value)
    raise TypeError()
```

This works nicely with primitive types. But I run into problems if I want to `safe_cast` against a UnionType:

```py
string = "string"
casted: str | int = safe_cast(str | int, string)
```

The instance check works with a union type. But my solution does not work, because mypy gives me

```
error: Argument 1 to "safe_cast" has incompatible type "UnionType"; expected "Type[<nothing>]"  [arg-type]
```

I figure that `<nothing>` refers to the unspecified type variable `T` here. I also figure that apparently mypy cannot resolve `Union[str, int]` to `Type[T]`. My question is: How can I solve this?

I looked into creating an overload for the UnionType. IIUC, in order to write the overload, I would need to create a Generic Union Type with a variadic number of arguments. I failed to get this done.

Is this the right direction? If yes, how do I get it done? If no, how can I solve my problem with `safe_cast`ing Union types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typing.cast` is likely to be special-cased in a type-checking implementation, because while this works in mypy,

```py
import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(t.cast(str | int, "string"))  # mypy: Revealed type is "Union[builtins.str, builtins.int]"
```

the [type annotations for `typing.cast` don't actually do anything meaningful](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/9472dc10b98570633e8777accf339dcec0179da4/stdlib/typing.pyi#L768-L773) with union types:

```py
@overload
def cast(typ: Type[_T], val: Any) -> _T: ...
@overload
def cast(typ: str, val: Any) -> Any: ...
@overload
def cast(typ: object, val: Any) -> Any: ...
```

What you'd actually want to do is to exploit the magic that your type-checker-implementation already offers. This is very easily done by making `typing.cast` your *typing API*, while making your `safe_cast` the *runtime implementation*.

```py
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar("T")

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import cast as safe_cast
else:
    # Type annotations don't actually matter here, but
    # are nice to provide for readability purposes.
    def safe_cast(t: type[T], value: t.Any) -> T:
        if isinstance(value, t):
            return value
        raise TypeError
```

```
>>> reveal_type(safe_cast(int | str, "string"))  # mypy: Revealed type is "Union[builtins.int, builtins.str]"
```

Comment: That is not just a great answer to my question, but also an interesting pattern I will remember for the future.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem, and apparently it is not possible to express this currently: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13498
but there is something in the works to allow this: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9773

for now i am doing the equivalent of this when passing in a type union:

```
casted: str | int = safe_cast(cast(type, str | int), string)
```

since i know using a type union will work with my code