Python function to assert a type and cast
Functions like scipy.optimize.fsolve have, uh, interesting APIs where setting the full_output parameter to a truthy value changes the return type in a way that type checkers can't infer.
I'd like a clean way to deal with statically typing this. Right now I am doing something like this:
result = fsolve(...)
assert isinstance(result, numpy.ndarray)
# .. call numpy array methods on `result` without any type errors ...

It'd be trivial to define a function to both cast and assert:
def assert_and_cast[T](obj: Any, typ: type[T]) -> T:
    assert isinstance(obj, typ)
    return obj # no need to cast(), checkers know it's type T

This would also be nice for cases where you know an optional variable is not-None:
my_var: Optional[dict] = ...

# ... some case where I know my_var isn't actually None ...

assert_and_cast(my_var, dict)['abc'] # this is not a type eror

Is there an existing function that does this? It seems like there would be since it's common in other languages (i.e. Guava's checkNotNull in Java, TypeScript's non-null assertion operator which both asserts and changes the type), but I can't find any common, existing one.

A non-None assert is just assert your_var is not None. Is that what you want?

Is there a function that does this? Didn't you write one, it's assert_and_cast?

It is my understanding that python as a very flexible language is ok in allowing functions to return multiple types and leave the user to choose what he/she wants to do with it. Some operations have both behaviours (like dict[key] vs dict.get()), some return placeholders like None and other raise errors.  If your function does something and you want the other, you should do what you did: e.g. use assert is not None, maybe use a decorator. You may also check unittest, there are methods that do what you need.

Ah yea to clarify, I know how to write this function. I'm curious if something like this is defined in a common place like Python's standard library.

This looks like the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75639679

Ah yes thank you!

Just FYI - there is also this function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.assert_type - this lets you assert the type but does nothing at runtime
